# Why is my line disappear in ggplot2?

Tags: r, shiny

```
output$paintplot <- renderPlotly({
validate(need(input$ProductLine, ""))
if(is.null(input$dateMonth)){return(NULL)}

if(input$select == "日") {
  p <- ggplot(data = p_A, aes(x = time, y = visit)) + xlab("時間") + ylab("關注度") + ggtitle(paste("折線圖-", input$dateMonth, "日")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

  df <- data.frame(A_date[[input$dateMonth]])
  df2 <- data.frame(B_date[[input$dateMonth]])
  df3 <- data.frame(C_date[[input$dateMonth]])
  df4 <- data.frame(D_date[[input$dateMonth]])
  df5 <- data.frame(E_date[[input$dateMonth]])
  df6 <- data.frame(visits_Frame_data[[input$dateMonth]])

  if(any(input$ProductLine == "iPhone 7")) {
    if(length(df$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df, size = 2, color="green", aes(text = "Item: iPhone 7")) + geom_line(data = df, color="green", aes(text = "Item: iPhone 7"))

  } 

  if (any(input$ProductLine == "iWatch 2")) {
    if(length(df2$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df2, size = 2, color="red", aes(text = "Item: iWatch 2")) + geom_line(data = df2, color="red", aes(text = "Item: iWatch 2"))
  } 

  if (any(input$ProductLine == "USB 3.0 64G")) {
    if(length(df3$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df3, size = 2, color="blue", aes(text = "Item: USB 3.0 64G")) + geom_line(data = df3, color="blue", aes(text = "Item: USB 3.0 64G"))
  } 

  if (any(input$ProductLine == "PS3")) {
    if(length(df4$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df4, size = 2, color="#58D3F7", aes(text = "Item: PS3")) + geom_line(data = df4, color="#58D3F7", aes(text = "Item: PS3"))
  } 

  if (any(input$ProductLine == "Sony XZ")) {
    if(length(df5$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df5, size = 2, color="#FA58F4", aes(text = "Item: Sony XZ")) + geom_line(data = df5, color="#FA58F4", aes(text = "Item: Sony XZ"))
  }

  if (any(input$ProductLine == "test")) {
    if(length(df6$date)==0){
      return(NULL)
    }
    p <- p + geom_point(data = df6, size = 2, color="#B292EA", aes(text = "Item: test")) + geom_line(data = df6, color="#B292EA", aes(text = "Item: test"))
  }
```

ui.R code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  includeCSS("css/main.css"),
  navbarPage("資料視覺化",
             tabPanel("分析圖",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          #add choices
                      selectizeInput("ProductLine", "選擇商品:",
                                     choices = c("Arduino", "iPhone 7", "iWatch 2",
                                                 "USB 3.0 64G", "PS3", "Sony XZ"),
                                     multiple = TRUE),
                      selectInput("select", "選擇顯示方式:",
                                  choices = c("日", "週")),
                      uiOutput("splitDate"),
                      uiOutput("weekList")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      plotlyOutput("paintplot", width=800,height=600)
                    )
                  )
         ),
         tabPanel("長條圖",
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      #add choices
                      selectInput("Productbar", "選擇商品:",
                                  choices = c("Arduino", "iPhone 7", "iWatch 2",
                                              "USB 3.0 64G", "PS3", "Sony XZ")),
                      selectInput("Barselect", "選擇顯示方式:",
                                  choices = c("日", "範圍")),
                      dateInput("splitDateBar", "選擇日期:", value = Sys.Date()),
                      uiOutput("hourList"),
                      tags$p("總平均關注度:"),
                      textOutput("text1")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      plotlyOutput("paintplotbar", width=800,height=600)

                    )
                  )
         )
  )
))
```

My question like this image.
[image: imahe_2]

But I change this code:

> ggplot(data = p_A, aes(x = date, y = visit)) + xlab("時間")

The line appeared, but this image is not my ideal.
[image: image_2]

I want to first image, but it must have line. What can I do? Please help for me. Thanks.

Comment: Should your x in the `aes` be time, like your previous `ggplot` calls?

Comment: @JakeKaupp What is mean?

Comment: Initially you have`p <- ggplot(data = p_A, aes(x = time, y = visit))` then you changed the x value to date in `ggplot(data = p_A, aes(x = date, y = visit)) + xlab("時間")`. Should it actually be time?

Comment: @JakeKaupp The code is my test "ggplot(data = p_A, aes(x = date, y = visit)) + xlab("時間")"  Sorry.  Actually be time.

Comment: where is your main.css file?

Comment: CSS file in the folder.